# Fiddler Capture Web.API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fiddler

I have this code that works.  I want to see the Web.API call, which is https://localhost:44335/ in Fiddler.  I want to see the Web.API call in Fiddler.  All I see is the POST to Index.  Can someone please tell me how to capture the request to https://localhost:44335.  Spent 5 hours researching answers, that did not work.

```
@using aModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Constants.Title_Home_Page;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        Import Cases
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("theFile", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var handler = new WebRequestHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            UseProxy = false,
            ReadWriteTimeout = 120000
        };

        var requestUri = $"api/File/SaveFile/";

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44335/") })
            {
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.InputStream.Length + 1];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = file.FileName };
                    content.Add(fileContent);
                    var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

API

```
public class FileController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412051/posting-file-from-mvc-to-web-api/43248473
    public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
                file.SaveAs(@"C:\myfolder\aFile.png");

                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your application does not make use of the default proxy configuration of Windows you have to explicitly add fiddler as http/https proxy in your `HttpClient` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to post in Postman and watch the traffic in Fiddler